# Swift UIDatePicker setDate does not respond

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

```
let timestamp = NSDate.now.addingTimeInterval(100000)
print(timestamp)
timePickerOutlet.datePickerMode = .time
timePickerOutlet.setDate(timestamp, animated: true)
```

is not working. Could someone tell why?

Comment: i think this code snippets not enough can you share details ?

Comment: The picker is inside a TableCell. Maybe it has to do with this?